# Vaadin, Jetty, Spring Data, Maven - Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, vaadin

I'm trying to integrate Spring Data within our Vaadin project. So I tried running the following sample code which uses the same technologies:

https://github.com/henrikerola/vaadin-spring-boot-todo

The only thing I changed is that I added jetty as we need to use it for our project.

Unfortunately, after `jetty:run` I'm getting the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype`

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.beta2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
           <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Any follow-up? I'm having a similar problem with the same exception, can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't had the chance to dig up the actual reason for this, but I suspect a classpath issue between jetty & tomcat which is preferred by spring-boot.

1. Anyhow, if you plan on further using spring-boot which is probably easiest, the [spring-boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat) offers an example of replacing tomcat with jetty, and it's simple as adding the following to your pom:

```js
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also, instead of running `mvn jetty-run` you'd probably want to run the `demo.DemoApplication` so it can properly discover the spring configuration and initialize the context.

2. If you plan on avoiding spring-boot, then remove the parent definition as well as the other boot dependencies and plugins. Also, remember to manually setup the application to initialize the spring context on starup.

Comment: 3 years later, this gave me the precious hint I needed! I needed to exclude one more thing from `spring-mobile` for this to work though: `<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth after two years: The error message tells you that `org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog` is not a subclass/implementation of `org.apache.juli.logging.Log`.

This happens if there are multiple jars containing the same class (`org.apache.juli.logging.Log` in this case I suppose) and multiple classloaders providing the same class (that are regarded as different in `instance-of` and `isAssignableFrom-checks`).

Check the jars that were downloaded for the occurrence of `org.apache.juli.logging.Log.class` and see where they are coming from. After adjusting that in your pom, you should be able to get rid off the error.